# Replacing every instance or a word in any form with JS

Tags: javascript

I am developing a mini chat program and want to redact profanity. How can I replace the word, for example, "replace" in any form like "rePlAce" or "RepLACe" without using `.toLowerCase()` or something of that sort?

I'm sorry if this is a poor question. I will try to edit it to become better at your suggestions.

Comment: why don't use toLowerCase()?

Comment: I can't think of anything to make this happen except `.toLowerCase()` which doesn't work since it changes the message to all lowercases.

For example. it would change the message "[profanity] WHAT?" to "[REDACTED] what?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method for strings accepts a regular expression pattern. You can use the [case insensitive](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp) modifier to ignore case differences in the search text.

```
let userMessage = "Please rePlAce me.";

let pattern = /replace/i;
userMessage = userMessage.replace(pattern, "******");

console.log(userMessage); // "Please ****** me.";
```

Note: the `replace()` method only replaces the first occurrence by default. You can include the [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) modifier to replace all instances.

```
let userMessage = "Please rePlAce this instance and repLAce this instance as well.";

let pattern = /replace/ig;
userMessage = userMessage.replace(pattern, "******");

console.log(userMessage); // "Please ****** this instance and ****** this instance as well."
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

### Own `toLowerCase()` Function

To convert to lowerCase you can write your own function.

- check if the ASCII Value of your letter is in the range of the upper case letters **65 - 90**. (picture below)
- If it is than give it an offset of 32 this is the corresponding lower case letter.

[image]

### ReplaceAll

Then convert your search word and the sentence to lower case and replace all the occurences with `replaceAll()`

```js
    let temper = "HoW";
    function convertToLowerCase(str) {
      let result = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (code > 64 && code < 91) {
          result += String.fromCharCode(code + 32);
        } else {
          result += str.charAt(i);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    // convert your string to lowercase
    let result = convertToLowerCase(temper);
    
    // then use the replace method of string
    
    let sentence = convertToLowerCase("Hello How Are how You HoW");
    console.log(sentence.replaceAll(result, "new"));
```

Comment: Ok, let me test this. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Wait, actually this isnt what I want.

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: ah you need the replace part?